# Why would NATO not defend its members against Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, nato

In [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/32648/9558) the following scenario is presented:

1. Russia invades a NATO member, say, Norway.
2. NATO does nothing to defend Norway.

In my opinion, this scenario is unrealistic because the very purpose of NATO is to defend its members from Soviet or Russian aggression.

[Article 5](https://www.nato.int/cps/ua/natohq/topics_110496.htm) states:

> Collective defence means that an attack against one Ally is considered as an attack against all Allies.

If Russia attacks, say, Estonia, it would face the same consequences as if it attacked the United States. Obviously, many people believe it's not the case.

What are rational, fact-backed reasons for the belief that NATO may not defend one or more of its members against Russian invasion?

Comment: A better question would be if Trump could veto such a thing. Because I haven't seen many others saying it's a bad idea. And more interestingly, what would happen in a confusing case, like just a massive terrorist attack in the Baltics. The US has invoked art. 5 on 9/11 https://www.nato.int/docu/review/2006/Invokation-Article-5/Invoking_Article_5/EN/index.htm

Comment: Because world wars are good and easy to win. Wait, did I miss a "not" there?

Comment: Even if Russia is bloodthirsty neighbor and price of life is equal to 0 there and even if other EU nations have in 2018 the weakest leaders like never before, I don't think that this is real case scenario for Norway. Norway is too important for EU stability and EU can't ignore fact with direct impact on NATO. If Russia attacks countries of EU/NATO then EU need to make strong pressure on NATO to go to war. If not, many national "brexits" will be triggered in a second and it will be an end of EU with huge impact on NATO. More anticipated is war comming from China.Just watch what is going there.

Comment: Russia's leaders aren't stupid.  They wouldn't *invade* Norway.  They would *subvert* it using socio-political maskirovka.

Comment: @DavidRicherby if you can plan to sit safely away from where the action evolves, then yes, pretty safe.

Comment: Not the same consequences.  USA would not exchange Los Angeles for Tallin (same can be said for most countries with their own cities).  But they would be consequences.  Actually, no one is really worried about that. The ROI is negative for Russia.

Comment: This question is related to https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9848/if-turkey-enters-in-war-are-other-nato-members-obligated-to-assist-her

Comment: @mojmir.novak For what it's worth, Norway is not, in fact, in the EU.

Comment: @owjburnham yes but it is part of _European Free Trade Association_ and _European Economic Area_ and _Schengen_. In other words, Norway is included in many _European structures_. European Union is in big crisis because _Schengen_ is failure. Millions of **former soldiers and killers** of defeated _Islamic state_ also called as _imigrants_ are incomming out of any control and Brexit is outcome of this failure. Krim is also failure. EU financial support of _Islamic state_ is failure. NATO and EU can't afford another one.

Comment: Is this a worldbuilding question where the aim is to come up with a plausible scenario where NATO does not defend its members against Russian aggression? If so I can write an answer, if not I can't really tell what this question is about.

Comment: "the very purpose of NATO is to defend its members from Soviet or Russian aggression." Can I have a source on that? While I do agree, I'm too tired of random hippies from land of rainbow unicorns trying to disprove it in other discussion.

Comment: Asking for a friend?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using military force is *one* way for NATO to counter aggression against one of its members, but not the only one. [Article 5 of the North Atlantic treaty reads](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/North_Atlantic_Treaty#Article_5):

> The Parties agree that an armed attack against one or more of them in Europe or North America shall be considered an attack against them all and consequently they agree that, if such an armed attack occurs, each of them, in exercise of the right of individual or collective self-defence recognised by Article 51 of the Charter of the United Nations, will assist the Party or Parties so attacked by taking forthwith, individually and in concert with the other Parties, **such action as it deems necessary, including the use of armed force**, to restore and maintain the security of the North Atlantic area.

(emphasis mine)

*Including* does not mean that it's the only option. So while the use of armed force is *one* way to respond to aggression, the NATO has several options, for example:

- Retaliate by sending troops to attack the territory of the aggressor directly
- Send troops to secure the attacked borders
- Provide the attacked with logistic support (money, weapons, intelligence, consultants etc.) but leave the actual fighting to them.
- Impose sanctions on the aggressor
- Nothing. They might decide that the best way to "restore and maintain security" is to just let the attacker have that country.

So if NATO makes the political decision to sacrifice a member in order to maintain peace and avoid a third world war, they would be free to do that. Whether this would be a *wise* decision would be a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. At the end of the day, the wording of the treaty is irrelevant. Whether they are theoretically free not to intervene is secondary, the cost of that response (all the way up to a  world war) would remain the main consideration for all those involved. That's the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote just yet, but what you're saying is basically that art 5 and the whole NATO thing is a worthless piece of paper, because the signatories can choose to do absolutely nothing if one is attacked. Clearly there' s something missing in this picture.

Comment: @Fizz: **All** treaties are worthless paper by that assessment.  Any sovereign state can abrogate any treaty it likes.  Other countries may retaliate (e.g. with sanctions or military force), but there is no international system of enforcement.

Comment: @Kevin: it's a fair point, but in the case of NATO there are more precise things one can say... so I typed them up in my own answer.

Comment: A postcard with the message "Good luck" would be enough.

Comment: I don’t think that your last point is valid and this is not part of the NATO idea or how the NATO is meant to be. Of course each country is at the end sovereign and can decide which action to take. But if in case of an attack the NATO parties decide to do nothing then from this moment on the NATO will be history.

Comment: Sacrificing a nation would, by definition, not be restoring security. And there's some ambiguity whether "it" in "such action as it deems necessary" refers to "each of them" or "the Party or Parties so attacked".

Answer (score 16):

> Why would the NATO not defend its members against Russia?

Lack of political will basically (for which one can find many reasons or justifications, of course). Each NATO country can choose how to respond to an article 5 invocation. This is why Trump's discourse (about maybe not defending a member) worries people. After a bit of digging, the promises in art. 5 exist in that guarded form [supposedly because](https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/18524):

> It is important to recall that the U.S. Executive
> Branch, which was responsible for negotiating the
> Treaty, insisted on qualified language in Article 5
> largely to assuage concerns in Congress. Congress,
> which has authority under the Constitution to declare
> war, did not want to cede that power to any
> multilateral organization.

And as a result, any country which depends on its parliament for going to war (this also includes Germany), can say "no thanks" to any NATO military action. Which basically means, to twist a term that any actual NATO defense is done by a [sub]alliance of the willing... (I'm not sure what can happen if Congress decides to go to war but the US President opposes it; that's probably worth a separate question.) By the way, article 42(7) of TEU is basically [in the same boat](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/RegData/etudes/BRIE/2015/572799/EPRS_BRI%282015%29572799_EN.pdf) as art 5 of NATO as far as its implications for obligation go. The advocates that wanted stronger promises to be made in TEU ran into the same problem with some countries wanting to have the option of staying aside in any collective defense action.

However, simply seeing it like this, ignores how NATO is [actually perceived by (most of) its own members, e.g.](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/the-power-of-nato-is-as-much-political-as-military):

> Q. How do you get countries on the eastern flank to devote resources to the southern flank, when Russia is almost literally breathing down their necks?
>
> A. It’s easier than you would think. Because every ally understands that the most important value of NATO is unity. If we don’t hang together, we will hang separately and so while Eastern allies are very understandably heavily focused on Russia they absolutely get it — that the alliance including they, themselves, have to contribute to concerns southern allies have. And the same is true the other way around, southern allies are absolutely engaged on challenges to NATO [from the east.]

So basically this is a big part of backbone of collective defense: if you chicken out in helping someone... there's a good chance they'll pay back the same. Which is probably why the US is the one making most of these not-gonna-help noises: they need other countries the least to defend their interests, or at least Trump thinks that. In particular since [in the case of Russia as enemy](https://www.economist.com/the-economist-explains/2015/03/09/how-natos-article-5-works)...

> The decision to act, or not, would be made not at NATO HQ in Brussels, but in Washington, DC. And, many eastern NATO members worry, it is hard to imagine an American president risking nuclear war to defend a tiny country half a world away.

Besides how NATO countries would actually react, it's also important to consider what its potential [enemies think NATO countries will do if one is attacked](https://www.economist.com/the-economist-explains/2015/03/09/how-natos-article-5-works):

> Article 5 says that the response may include armed force, but it does not mandate it. All that NATO actually promises is to take “such action as it deems necessary” to restore and maintain security. That could be anything from nuclear war to a stiff diplomatic protest. Three tricky considerations would determine the precise nature of any NATO response to foreign aggression. The first is geography: in places where an aggressor can quickly complete and consolidate an invasion, NATO's options are very limited. The Baltics, for instance, occupy a thin flat strip of land which is all but indefensible. A Russian surprise attack could reach the coast within hours, and reversing a successful Russian invasion would be hard, even futile. Yet that was also true of West Berlin. The Baltics argue that an attack on them would mean an all-out East-West confrontation thanks to Article 5. If Russia believes that, deterrence is working. But Article 5 does not specify such a response.

That it comes down to: perception is reality in this case. It doesn't matter that the treaty says NATO countries can do nothing... if Russia thinks that's not the likely response to its aggression. That's why many NATO people worry about Trump busting this perception in eyes of the world.

And finally, there's another aspect consider: ongoing military cooperation, besides enhanced cooperative readiness, also gives a potential "Pearl Harbour effect" (if I may coin a term) [for US troops stationed near Russia's border](https://www.economist.com/free-exchange/2014/04/15/this-is-not-a-game-theory):

> Another option would be to put American soldiers in harm's way, so that Russia could not invade NATO territory without directly harming American military personnel. Given that America could not help but respond forcefully to an attack on its own people, such a move might render the NATO guarantee toothy. Not toothless. So, basically, man the NATO-Russian border with American troops.

It doesn't have that close, but you can see that having to dispose of some American targets (e.g. air power or even just AWACS, or anti-ballistic missiles) in Eastern Europe could be a big problem for Russia if it has the potential to create a "Pearl Harbor effect" (albeit not on US soil) that could enrage the US public and the Congress. Political will can materialize surprisingly quickly in such a case; even a just a proportionate US response could mean trouble for Russia as an aggressor in this case.

So my point with this is that while on paper the NATO treaty may look weak, the deterrence effect can well exceed what simple reading of the text might conclude... as long as the magic is not busted by talk to the contrary.

Comment: Some concrete articles on US pre-positioning forces in Eastern Europe: 
[land](https://www.defensenews.com/land/2017/07/13/us-army-s-first-heavy-brigade-rotation-in-europe-learns-newfound-agility/); [air](https://www.defensenews.com/smr/nato-priorities/2018/06/25/poking-the-bear-us-air-force-builds-in-russias-backyard/)

Comment: +1. Compare how the political will in France and Britain to defend Poland, which had been attacked and overrun by Germany, was lacking: [*Pourquoi mourir pour Dantzig?*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21346/1352) (Yes, I know that both *did* declare war on Germany and that the "phony war" was [anything but](https://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2018/08/phony-phony-war.html), and that Dan(t)zig was *de jure* a Free City, not part of Poland.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa I think the first link in your comment is broken, unless the invasion of Poland had something to do with a linear algebra textbook.

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo: thanks! (No, AFAIK, it didn't.) [Here is the correct link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_Die_for_Danzig%3F)

Answer (score 12):

Nobody mentioned the elephant in the room right now; NATO is also unlikely to defend a member if this member goes rogue and act upon their own.

**I am talking about Turkey.**

The 1952 Turkey which joined the NATO is different from the 2018 Turkey. During the former time the military hold strict to [Kemalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kemalism) and every attempt to revitalize islamic fundamentalism in Turkish society was prevented, sometimes even by a coup (e.g. 1960). The islamist party was forbidden and changed names regularly: National Order Party, National Salvation Party, Welfare Party, Virtue Party, finally AKP. Now 2018 the military has lost its influence and Turkey is moving into the direction of a full-fledged dictatorship and islamization of the country.

Turkey has isolated itself internationally more and more, the EU is just weakly pretending to take the former attempts for membership seriously. While the hatred for the Kurds and their supporting troops ([YPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Protection_Units)) is nothing new, the shown sympathies for ISIL are alarming. [Shooting down a russian jet in 2015 without consulting the allies did not help to give the impression that Turkey's command is trustworthy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Russian_Sukhoi_Su-24_shootdown) Turkey had made steps to reconcile with Russia to defuse the situation, but I think currently NATO would think twice about defending Turkey if an attack on Russia is not in their interest and Turkey attacks unprovoked.

I think the USA still is prone to overestimate their relations with useful partners (using [Turkey's airbases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incirlik_Air_Base) for second-strike capability with their bombers) and underestimate the danger such irregular partners pose.

Comment: Also, Turkey has invaded Syria.

Comment: NATO's treaty is only for mutual self defense, if a "rogue" member invades or attacks another country members have NO obligation to assist it.

Comment: @RandyHill The words on treaties are often ignored. There is no accepted due process in international relationships which looks up if treaties are correctly interpreted. False flag operations claiming an attack to justify a "defense" are one of the oldest tricks in the books, see Gleiwitz incident. The NATO for example called for collective defense in the wake of the 9/11 attacks *despite al-Quaeda being a non-state actor and therefore not a subject of a treaty between countries (This was explicitly mentioned in the ICJ decision in case of Nicaragua 1986)*.

Comment: @ThorstenS. I'm not sure what point you are trying to make. You said it NATO was "unlikely" to defend a rogue member that attacked another country, I'm pointing out the NATO treaty specifically provides no obligation to defend any member who starts a war with another another country. Donald Trump may want to defend Turkey if it attacks Greece, or not want to defend Germany if it's attacked by Russia (or Congress may refuse to authorize either). Both of those political decisions have nothing to do with what the actual treaty commitments are.

Comment: @RandyHill Let's say as Turkey attacks Iran. Iran has quite a bad reputation among NATO members, so who guarantees that *NATO does not declare that Iran attacked first, so collective defense is necessary?*. **Words don't matter much if the persons judging them are the same who are making the decisions.** If on the other hand Israel attacks Turkey, I think NATO will do everything in their might to defuse the situation even if from an objective evaluation the conditions for collective defense have been fulfilled. I am just saying you have too much confidence that words of treaties matter.

Comment: See also: [*Does NATO membership require democracy?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11773/130)

Answer (score 7):

The main reason not to intervene would be the cost of a war (starting with the monetary and human costs of waging war for the helping nations all the way to the risk of escalation to a larger conflict and an attack on the mainland). That's perfectly rational even if you have multiple treaties with the nation being attacked.

During the cold war, that was a major aspect of strategic thinking in a country like France. While France and the US were broadly aligned, France was very keen on keeping some autonomy in its relationship with the Soviet Union, developing its own nuclear weapons, etc. because it was afraid that when push came to shove, the US would decide to sacrifice Western Europe rather than commit hundreds of thousands of men to fight a new world war. Interestingly, during both world wars the US did intervene and contribute greatly the winning side but it didn't do it immediately and not without debate.

Even with a mutual defense treaty, countries will rationally evaluate these costs anew when faced with such a consequential move as attacking a powerful opponent like the Soviet Union (and, to a lesser extent, present-day Russia). But no treaty is going to guarantee in and of itself that, say, the US spends billions of dollars and thousands of lives to defend another country.

So while it does contain a mutual defense clause, the purpose of the NATO treaty is a bit more subtle. What it does (besides all the technical aspects like common military standards and extensive operational collaboration) is increase the costs of reneging on a commitment. Once countries publicly committed to a mutual defense agreement, failing to act on it is signalling weakness and making them worthless as an ally, thus decreasing their overall power and influence in the world. That, in turn, means that an attack on a *bona fide* NATO member is a challenge to the US, which needs to be treated as such. But that's still not quite the same as being attacked and the cost-benefit considerations therefore differ.

Comment: Another side effect of the NATO treaty is standardization of communication (including digital), camouflage, weapon systems, tactics, and so on. When needed, the NATO can operate as a single army (provided the politicians manage to find an answer to "who's in command?").

Comment: @Sjoerd That's the technical aspects I am alluding to.

Answer (score 3):

The NATO and Russia of today are different than the NATO and Russia of the Cold War. The rationale behind the founding of NATO was to deter the Soviet Union from invading europe. The founding members are the US and a bunch of western european nations. The most likely conflict-scenario was more or less all-out war.

Nowadays, with ex-soviet republics being NATO members (the baltic states), or being interested in joining ([Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine%E2%80%93NATO_relations)), the situation is much more complicated, as one can argue that today-Russia is trying to win back some of the ground lost during the collapse of the Soviet Union and Russia's phase of relative weakness in the 90s, e.g. eastern Ukraine or Crimea.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer stops the moment it starts to get interesting. In what way is the situation "more complicated"? How do these "more complicated" circumstances affect the likeliness of a coordinated military response against hypothetical Russian aggression?

Answer (score 0):

The why is that the Russian Federation has the strongest military presence in Europe, and to avoid all out war with Russia in the European theater, and elsewhere. NATO members also import substantial natural resources from Russia, making it "bad for business" to go to war with the Russian Federation based solely on the fact that one of their neighbor nations states or even allies are invaded or annexed by the Russian Federation.

Comment: (-1) It has become a frequent talking point the Budapest Memorandum was transparently weak, a comparison with NATO makes no sense, cf. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/7899/why-dont-signatories-of-budapest-memorandum-on-security-assurances-except-russ/7904#7904

Comment: @Relaxed Firstly, you do not clearly define what you mean by the term "weak". Secondly, you make the flawed assumption that the inverse of the first undefined term as applied to NATO is true, that is, that NATO is **not** "weak".

Comment: You're resorting to sophistry. “Weakness” is not some deep concept, it's really just a trivial point. I don't care whether NATO is “weak” or not or to give a precise definition, the fact is that its founding treaty includes much stronger wording. Read the linked page for more details if you are interested.

Comment: @Relaxed _"Whether they are theoretically free not to intervene is secondary, the cost of that response (all the way up to a world war) would remain the main consideration for all those involved. That's the answer to the OP's question."_ That is precisely what stated at this answer to this question at the last paragraph. If you are going to apply that as rationale for "the answer to the OP's question", then do so uniformly, else your "down" vote is fraudulent in nature on its face.

Comment: I am open to revising my vote if you make that point clearer and edit out the irrelevant commentary on the Budapest Memorandum. As it stands, your answer does not clearly make it. Speaking about “fraudulent vote”, I see you downvoted my other answer in retaliation but failed to provide any cogent argument. Are you unable to comprehend the difference in tone and contents between article 5 of the NATO treaty and the text of the Budapest Memorandum?

Comment: @Relaxed Since the question proffers a hypothetical scenario, in this users estimation the closest to **fact**, which is what OP asks for, is the annexation of Crimea by the Russian Federation. In what way should the answer be edited? _"I see you downvoted my other answer in retaliation but failed to provide any cogent argument."_ That is an inaccurate accusation, which could have been quickly dispelled in your own mind by checking the total number of "down" votes this user has cast at all SE accounts: **0**.

Comment: @guest271314 Ukraine is not member of the NATO. My question is about when Russia attacks a proper NATO member (not a country that **wants** to become a member).

Comment: @FranzDrollig _"My question is about when Russia attacks a proper NATO membe"_ That is pure speculation. The closest scenario in **fact** (_"What are rational, fact-backed reasons"_) that can fathom in recent history is the annexation of Crimea by the Russian Federation. In short, the _why_ would be to avoid war and to continue doing business (imports/exports).

Comment: @guest271314 Re "That is pure speculation. " It's not. Baltic states (Estonia, Lithuania, Latvia) were training their armed forces for precisely that scenario couple of years ago.

Comment: @FranzDrollig _"Obviously, many people believe it's not the case."_ Then why did you include the preceding qualifying assessment of the political realities in your question? The political reality is that interests, including nation states, prefer to not be engaged in war (e.g., "Baltic states (Estonia, Lithuania, Latvia)"), unless their overall strategy is war and aggrandizement; that is, imperialism, colonialism.

Comment: @guest271314 Edited by removing references to the Budapest agreement (which is, again, so different as to be irrelevant) and emphasizing the point you said you wanted to make, namely that a war would cost a lot.

Comment: @Relaxed That is fair enough. Edited. Those nations states which are cognizant of Russian Federal foreign policy and practice did nothing then and do nothing now to assist Crimea is an example of non-action while simultaneously expecting assistance from others if Russian Federation attempts to annex their states.

Comment: @FranzDrollig Why did Estonia, Lithuania, Latvia not go to the aid of Ukraine, given they allege the same nation state will potentially invade their nation states?

Comment: @Relaxed Why have you not yet responded in kind by retracting your "down" vote based on the suggested and completed edit?

Comment: @guest271314 Re "Why did Estonia, Lithuania, Latvia not go to the aid of Ukraine?"": Because Baltic countries don't have a contract that obliges them to provide military assistance to Ukraine (AFAIK). NATO members do have such obligation to each other. My question is about NATO members.

Comment: @FranzDrollig A contract is meaningless when faced with military aggression, or even when there is no military aggression. The actual political economy is at the forefront of consideration, not words on pieces of paper: the heat has to stay on to keep soldiers warm if they are to face the Russian Federation. Many have historically failed to deal with Russian winters during armed conflict. The Russian military is not a paper tiger which can be overcome by some archaic contractual agreement between nation states which are actually empowered by only a few, potentially unpredictably ruled, nations

Comment: @guest271314 Because I am not checking this site every five minutes?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm downvoting, not for disagreement, but because this does not answer the question.